# Issue with sending Buddypress/Buddyboss message as anonymous user

Tags: php, wordpress, buddypress, buddyboss

I have created a custom function that adds a checkbox to the end of newly composed private messages within Buddyboss/Buddypress that allows the user to send messages anonymously.

If the check box is ticked, then the sender id should be 55, as I've created a user named Anonymous with the userID of 55. I want messages to appear as if they were sent from that user if the checkbox is ticked.

Here is the code:

```
function bp_add_anonymous_checkbox() {
    if ( bp_is_active( 'messages' ) ) {
        // Only show the checkbox if the user is composing a private message
        if ( bp_is_messages_component() && bp_is_current_action( 'compose' ) ) {
            // Output the checkbox
            ?>
            <p>
                <label for="bp-anonymous-message">
                    <input type="checkbox" name="bp-anonymous-message" id="bp-anonymous-message" value="1">
                    Send this message anonymously
                </label>
            </p>
            <?php
        }
    }
}
add_action( 'bp_after_messages_compose_content', 'bp_add_anonymous_checkbox' );

function bp_anonymous_message_handler( $recipients, $subject, $content, $date_sent ) {
    // Check if the anonymous message checkbox was checked
    if ( ! empty( $_POST['bp-anonymous-message'] ) ) {
        // Set the sender of the message to the user with an ID of 55
        $sender_id = 55;
    } else {
        // Otherwise, use the current user's ID as the sender
        $sender_id = get_current_user_id();
    }
 
    // Send the message as usual
    return messages_new_message( $recipients, $subject, $content, $date_sent, $sender_id );
}
add_filter( 'messages_message_before_save', 'bp_anonymous_message_handler', 10, 4 );
```

I have successfully been able to add the function, but it does not appear to execute. I don't get any error, it simply just never sends the message nor does it refresh after I've hit the send button. I believe it might related to the filter I've added at the end. Am I missing something?

Answer (score 0):

`messages_message_before_save` is not a filter hook, although it can be used to filter the args.

```
do_action_ref_array( 'messages_message_before_save', array( &$this ) );
```

[Review the context of the hook](https://www.buddyboss.com/resources/reference/classes/bp_messages_message/send/)

[Review do_action_ref_array](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/do_action_ref_array/)